# How to align X/Y ranges of different scatter plots in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm plotting several scatter plots with X/Y data. The problem is that, in order to compare the plots, the **X/Y axes need to be aligned**. I can do this manually but would definitely prefer an automatic solution.

For illustration, I use here one data set from which I want to plot two subsets (in reality though I have two or more completely independent data sets, each with their own time line!) The dataset as a whole is given below.

First plot:

```
ggplot(df[1:100,], aes(x=X, y= Y, color=starttime_ms)) +
  geom_point(size = 0.5) + 
  scale_color_gradientn(colors = c("forestgreen", "gold", "red"), name = "time (ms)") +
  stat_density2d()
```

The second plot:

```
ggplot(df[100:200,], aes(x=X, y= Y, color=starttime_ms)) +
  geom_point(size = 0.5) + 
  scale_color_gradientn(colors = c("forestgreen", "gold", "red"), name = "time (ms)") +
  stat_density2d()
```

The result:

[image]

As can be seen the X/Y axes cover different ranges. How can they be aligned? (And if I may add a second question: how can the two plots be produced in one go and shown immediately side-by-side?)

**EDIT**:
I've found a solution to the second question - using the package `cowplot` - so only the question of how to align the X/Y axes of two independent data sets remains to be answered.

```
library(cowplot)
a <- ggplot(df[1:100,], aes(x=X, y= Y, color=starttime_ms)) +
  geom_point(size = 0.5) + 
  scale_color_gradientn(colors = c("forestgreen", "gold", "red"), name = "time (ms)") +
  stat_density2d()

b <- ggplot(df[100:200,], aes(x=X, y= Y, color=starttime_ms)) +
  geom_point(size = 0.5) + 
  scale_color_gradientn(colors = c("forestgreen", "gold", "red"), name = "time (ms)") +
  stat_density2d()

plot_grid(a, b)
```

Data:

```
df <- structure(list(X = c(886.995, 876.414, 890.29, 870.686, 889.886, 
                           878.858, 893.737, 875.862, 889.03, 878.506, 888.412, 879.659, 
                           869.97, 813.237, 825.718, 820.695, 833.845, 809.99, 827.442, 
                           822.203, 833.764, 813.335, 836.974, 823.124, 840.259, 829.392, 
                           839.988, 817.891, 834.928, 826.655, 834.157, 824.684, 834.119, 
                           826.621, 835.76, 825.053, 835.486, 826.374, 836.49, 834.75, 846.584, 
                           834.155, 847.473, 831.293, 842.564, 830.842, 842.428, 828.199, 
                           841.25, 823.716, 838.123, 823.475, 840.047, 830.131, 845.919, 
                           821.53, 835.386, 830.319, 837.443, 827.744, 838.258, 837.11, 
                           847.505, 827.565, 838.85, 823.371, 838.15, 856.02, 887.157, 867.535, 
                           887.932, 864.748, 877.356, 866.45, 880.88, 863.509, 879.835, 
                           868.479, 875.554, 862.731, 875.356, 859.63, 869.753, 860.095, 
                           871.778, 853.611, 870.142, 852.563, 869.566, 858.956, 872.494, 
                           852.913, 873.889, 856.914, 867.625, 858.928, 876.012, 861.61, 
                           851.618, 788.261, 798.379, 777.557, 798.956, 777.083, 801.887, 
                           778.075, 798.864, 785.822, 799.679, 781.541, 795.737, 785.299, 
                           795.836, 792.412, 799.156, 776.022, 792.404, 787.949, 781.935, 
                           793.567, 771.902, 707.73, 779.717, 788.547, 767.614, 792.656, 
                           774.669, 817.467, 808.79, 821.175, 804.167, 817.827, 804.583, 
                           819.402, 806.682, 818.105, 809.101, 820.088, 795.661, 817.472, 
                           806.363, 817.635, 803.629, 813.491, 800.27, 800.459, 758.664, 
                           785.968, 772.512, 781.696, 769.386, 792.597, 778.636, 793.8, 
                           779.889, 797.779, 777.738, 799.166, 785.231, 795.49, 783.717, 
                           798.131, 786.995, 795.558, 783.907, 798.121, 792.489, 801.123, 
                           793.859, 802.535, 796.445, 800.297, 783.966, 796.06, 774.731, 
                           779.655, 710.941, 721.324, 690.261, 726.259, 664.783, 706.26, 
                           653.884, 699.744, 669.978, 725.24, 711.67, 753.881, 756.447, 
                           795.456, 795.915, 870.223, 855.74, 880.141, 873.236, 901.025, 
                           899.759, 916.765, 915.548, 941.198), Y = c(664.026, 658.045, 
                                                                      661.254, 659.364, 664.259, 655.926, 663.828, 659.352, 663.331, 
                                                                      656.485, 663.223, 653.781, 665.414, 674.523, 692.033, 683.056, 
                                                                      690.348, 683.422, 691.038, 683.172, 690.431, 681.307, 691.108, 
                                                                      679.978, 685.968, 679.486, 685.47, 682.479, 686.535, 679.308, 
                                                                      687.094, 682.646, 686.844, 679.004, 686.636, 679.37, 687.812, 
                                                                      677.968, 686.345, 672.169, 685.389, 675.053, 688.141, 675.668, 
                                                                      687.256, 676.59, 688.574, 678.659, 689.709, 679.089, 687.647, 
                                                                      680.711, 689.211, 679.563, 684.627, 680.587, 688.103, 678.541, 
                                                                      687.672, 678.981, 685.274, 676.507, 684.368, 678.961, 686.621, 
                                                                      681.139, 688.232, 672.178, 663.962, 656.615, 661.313, 655.927, 
                                                                      662.064, 654.477, 663.896, 659.962, 668.294, 662.895, 668.242, 
                                                                      662.718, 670.333, 662.663, 670.956, 664.628, 674.369, 667.075, 
                                                                      673.834, 666.489, 671.39, 664.739, 673.173, 666.36, 671.923, 
                                                                      666.652, 673.249, 664.564, 673.67, 663.489, 686.796, 719.946, 
                                                                      721.271, 721.361, 722.227, 723.032, 721.333, 721.793, 721.419, 
                                                                      723.948, 724.301, 722.893, 723.387, 722.16, 722.367, 720.927, 
                                                                      725.513, 723.396, 726.414, 722.724, 726.956, 730.555, 728.354, 
                                                                      784.936, 729.929, 730.318, 732.103, 730.996, 727.628, 713.195, 
                                                                      708.602, 711.194, 708.453, 713.616, 711.269, 715.176, 709.092, 
                                                                      716.382, 707.973, 715.003, 712.65, 716.613, 708.856, 717.138, 
                                                                      711.883, 717.754, 712.86, 726.009, 738.927, 741.762, 736.506, 
                                                                      741.965, 738.143, 741.771, 736.247, 740.68, 736.025, 738.213, 
                                                                      733.757, 736.281, 731.712, 737.712, 732.11, 738.117, 731.557, 
                                                                      740.61, 732.95, 736.509, 730.86, 734.704, 726.97, 731.913, 724.131, 
                                                                      732.462, 730.361, 738.381, 732.796, 736.228, 738.229, 746.993, 
                                                                      739.654, 734.988, 735.721, 734.151, 725.623, 732.994, 721.506, 
                                                                      718.839, 702.851, 705.922, 693.595, 690.521, 677.954, 667.812, 
                                                                      643.589, 647.281, 630.427, 631.522, 615.858, 621.84, 607.178, 
                                                                      609.407), starttime_ms = c(329011, 329028, 329045, 329061, 329078, 
                                                                                                 329095, 329111, 329128, 329145, 329161, 329178, 329195, 329211, 
                                                                                                 329228, 329245, 329261, 329278, 329295, 329311, 329328, 329345, 
                                                                                                 329361, 329378, 329395, 329411, 329428, 329445, 329461, 329478, 
                                                                                                 329495, 329511, 329528, 329545, 329561, 329578, 329595, 329611, 
                                                                                                 329628, 329645, 329661, 329678, 329695, 329711, 329728, 329745, 
                                                                                                 329761, 329778, 329795, 329811, 329828, 329845, 329861, 329878, 
                                                                                                 329895, 329911, 329928, 329945, 329961, 329978, 329995, 330011, 
                                                                                                 330028, 330045, 330061, 330078, 330095, 330111, 330128, 330145, 
                                                                                                 330161, 330178, 330195, 330211, 330228, 330245, 330261, 330278, 
                                                                                                 330295, 330311, 330328, 330345, 330361, 330378, 330395, 330411, 
                                                                                                 330428, 330445, 330461, 330478, 330495, 330511, 330528, 330545, 
                                                                                                 330561, 330578, 330595, 330611, 330628, 330645, 330661, 330678, 
                                                                                                 330695, 330711, 330728, 330745, 330761, 330778, 330795, 330811, 
                                                                                                 330828, 330845, 330861, 330878, 330895, 330911, 330928, 330945, 
                                                                                                 330961, 330995, 331011, 331028, 331045, 331061, 331078, 331095, 
                                                                                                 331111, 331128, 331145, 331161, 331178, 331195, 331211, 331228, 
                                                                                                 331245, 331261, 331278, 331295, 331311, 331328, 331345, 331361, 
                                                                                                 331378, 331395, 331411, 331428, 331445, 331461, 331478, 331495, 
                                                                                                 331511, 331528, 331545, 331561, 331578, 331595, 331611, 331628, 
                                                                                                 331645, 331661, 331678, 331695, 331711, 331728, 331745, 331761, 
                                                                                                 331778, 331795, 331811, 331828, 331845, 331861, 331878, 331895, 
                                                                                                 331911, 331928, 331945, 331961, 331978, 331995, 332011, 332028, 
                                                                                                 332045, 332061, 332078, 332095, 332111, 332128, 332145, 332161, 
                                                                                                 332178, 332195, 332211, 332228, 332245, 332261, 332278, 332295, 
                                                                                                 332311, 332328, 332345)), row.names = c(42488L, 42491L, 42493L, 
                                                                                                                                         42497L, 42499L, 42502L, 42504L, 42507L, 42509L, 42512L, 42514L, 
                                                                                                                                         42517L, 42519L, 42522L, 42524L, 42527L, 42529L, 42532L, 42534L, 
                                                                                                                                         42537L, 42539L, 42542L, 42544L, 42547L, 42549L, 42552L, 42554L, 
                                                                                                                                         42557L, 42559L, 42562L, 42564L, 42567L, 42569L, 42572L, 42574L, 
                                                                                                                                         42577L, 42579L, 42582L, 42584L, 42587L, 42589L, 42592L, 42594L, 
                                                                                                                                         42597L, 42599L, 42602L, 42604L, 42607L, 42609L, 42612L, 42614L, 
                                                                                                                                         42618L, 42620L, 42623L, 42625L, 42628L, 42630L, 42634L, 42636L, 
                                                                                                                                         42640L, 42642L, 42646L, 42648L, 42651L, 42653L, 42656L, 42658L, 
                                                                                                                                         42661L, 42663L, 42666L, 42668L, 42671L, 42673L, 42676L, 42678L, 
                                                                                                                                         42681L, 42683L, 42686L, 42688L, 42691L, 42693L, 42696L, 42698L, 
                                                                                                                                         42701L, 42703L, 42706L, 42708L, 42711L, 42713L, 42716L, 42718L, 
                                                                                                                                         42721L, 42723L, 42726L, 42728L, 42731L, 42733L, 42736L, 42738L, 
                                                                                                                                         42742L, 42744L, 42748L, 42750L, 42754L, 42756L, 42759L, 42761L, 
                                                                                                                                         42764L, 42766L, 42769L, 42771L, 42774L, 42776L, 42779L, 42781L, 
                                                                                                                                         42784L, 42786L, 42789L, 42794L, 42796L, 42799L, 42801L, 42805L, 
                                                                                                                                         42807L, 42811L, 42813L, 42816L, 42818L, 42821L, 42823L, 42826L, 
                                                                                                                                         42828L, 42831L, 42833L, 42837L, 42839L, 42842L, 42844L, 42847L, 
                                                                                                                                         42849L, 42852L, 42854L, 42857L, 42859L, 42862L, 42864L, 42867L, 
                                                                                                                                         42869L, 42872L, 42874L, 42877L, 42879L, 42883L, 42885L, 42888L, 
                                                                                                                                         42890L, 42893L, 42895L, 42898L, 42900L, 42903L, 42905L, 42908L, 
                                                                                                                                         42910L, 42913L, 42915L, 42918L, 42920L, 42923L, 42925L, 42928L, 
                                                                                                                                         42930L, 42933L, 42935L, 42938L, 42940L, 42943L, 42945L, 42948L, 
                                                                                                                                         42950L, 42953L, 42955L, 42958L, 42960L, 42963L, 42965L, 42968L, 
                                                                                                                                         42970L, 42973L, 42975L, 42978L, 42980L, 42983L, 42985L, 42988L, 
                                                                                                                                         42990L, 42993L, 42995L, 42998L, 43000L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: try using `facet_wrap()` with the `scales = "fixed"` argument.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one method. Start by storing the plots:

```r
library(ggplot2)

p1 <- ggplot(df[1:100,], aes(x=X, y= Y, color=starttime_ms)) +
  geom_point(size = 0.5) + 
  scale_color_gradientn(colors = c("forestgreen", "gold", "red"), 
                        name = "time (ms)") +
  stat_density2d()

p2 <- ggplot(df[100:200,], aes(x=X, y= Y, color=starttime_ms)) +
  geom_point(size = 0.5) + 
  scale_color_gradientn(colors = c("forestgreen", "gold", "red"), 
                        name = "time (ms)") +
  stat_density2d()
```

Now get the combined x and y axis limits, with pretty breaks, and assign them to each plot:

```r
xbreaks <- pretty(c(layer_data(p1)$x, layer_data(p2)$x))
ybreaks <- pretty(c(layer_data(p1)$y, layer_data(p2)$y))

p1 <- p1 + scale_x_continuous(breaks = xbreaks, limits = range(xbreaks)) +
           scale_y_continuous(breaks = ybreaks, limits = range(ybreaks))

p2 <- p2 + scale_x_continuous(breaks = xbreaks, limits = range(xbreaks)) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = ybreaks, limits = range(ybreaks))
```

Both plots will now have the same x and y axis. To plot them together on the same page, we simply use the patchwork package:

```r
library(patchwork)

p1 + p2
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot - beautiful!

Answer (score 2):

As @PaulStaffordAllen suggests, `facet_wrap` is the way to go.  To use it, you need to add a column to your data that defines the facets.

```
df %>% 
  mutate(group=row_number() <= 100)  %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=X, y= Y, color=starttime_ms, group=group)) +
    geom_point(size = 0.5) + 
    scale_color_gradientn(colors = c("forestgreen", "gold", "red"), name = "time (ms)") +
    stat_density2d() +
    facet_wrap(vars(group))
```

[image]

The `group=group` in the `aes()` call should calculate statistics (ie the density and colour) within facets, but this plot does not match your separate graphs.  I'm not sufficiently familiar with your data to know why that might be.  But I notice your colour scales are different between the two plots as well as the axes...

Comment: Thanks for this, already quite useful. But using the two subsets of one and the same data set was just for illustrative purposes. In reality I have two (or more) completely independent data sets, each with its own time line. Therefore each plot needs to have its own time key. How can that be achieved?

Comment: @ChrisRuehlemann If you have independent plots then the `patchwork` approach shown by Allan Cameron is going to be better I think.

Comment: I agree.  Given the additional constraints you mention in your comment, `patchwork` (or `cowplot`) would be a better option.